# ArrayOutOfBoundException when reading test data from Excel

Tags: automated-testing, java

I am very new to Selenium RC. Please, help in my question.

1. I installed jxl.jar file (Java library for Excel) and added it to Eclipse build path.
2. I created an Excel file as readdata.xls where I entered some columns like username and password and provided some example inputs for those columns. Something like:

   ```
   UserName  Password
   Akshit    Ak12345
   Ashwika   AS12345
   ```
3. I wrote the following code

   ```
   package seleniumscripts;

   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import jxl.Sheet;
   import jxl.Workbook;


   public class Excelreaddata {

       private static String husername;
       private static String hpassword;
       private static String username;
       private static String password;

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Home\\Desktop\\Readdata.xls");
           Workbook wb = Workbook .getWorkbook(fis);
           Sheet s= wb.getSheet(0);

           Excelreaddata.husername =s.getCell(0,0).getContents();
           Excelreaddata.hpassword =s.getCell(0,1).getContents();
           System.out.println(Excelreaddata.husername);
           System.out.println(Excelreaddata.hpassword);

           Excelreaddata.username =s.getCell(1,0).getContents();
           Excelreaddata.password =s.getCell(1,1).getContents();
           System.out.println(Excelreaddata.username);
           System.out.println(Excelreaddata.password);             

           Excelreaddata.username =s.getCell(2,0).getContents();
           Excelreaddata.password =s.getCell(2,1).getContents();
           System.out.println(Excelreaddata.username);
           System.out.println(Excelreaddata.password);     
       }
   }
   ```

My question is: when executing the code results are displayed only for Akshit, not for Ashwika. I need both to display.

Result I am getting like this when executing in Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
  at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:288)
  at seleniumscripts.Excelreaddata.main(Excelreaddata.java:38)

UserName
Akshit
Password
Ak12345
```

Comment: Welcome to SQA, jyotsna. Your problem has nothing to do with Selenium, it is more about Excel library you use. I clarified the title accordingly.

Comment: Down voted as although it has full details it is programming not testing

Comment: @Phil, I agree. Still the question can teach users how to isolate a defect, which is an important skill in testing :-) That's why in my answer I tried to to demonstrate how to read logs, code and API documentation instead of giving a solution only.

Comment: You gave a great answer - but we need to reach users to post questions in the right place ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Defect isolation**

The stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
  at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:288)
  at seleniumscripts.Excelreaddata.main(Excelreaddata.java:38)
```

suggests that you are trying to access a cell that does not exist in the given sheet.

I cannot match line numbers in stacktrace wuth your code, but this probably is thrown in

```
Excelreaddata.username =s.getCell(2,0).getContents();
```

If you consult [JavaDoc](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html#getCell%28int,%20int%29) of the `Sheet` class, you will see that first parameter stands for column. You are requesting 3rd column (column/row indexes are 0-based, so 0, 1, 2, ...), whereas you mentioned in Excel file you have only two columns.

For the same reason, when you try to display username and password of the first user:

```
 Excelreaddata.husername =s.getCell(0,0).getContents();
 Excelreaddata.hpassword =s.getCell(0,1).getContents();
 System.out.println(Excelreaddata.husername);
 System.out.println(Excelreaddata.hpassword);
```

you get a column name and username of the first user instead:

```
UserName
Akshit
```

**Solution**

You should switch the order of parameters in your code.

```
// Print 1st user's name and password 
Excelreaddata.husername =s.getCell(0,1).getContents();
Excelreaddata.hpassword =s.getCell(1,1).getContents();
...
// Print 3rd user's name and password
Excelreaddata.husername =s.getCell(0,3).getContents();
Excelreaddata.hpassword =s.getCell(1,3).getContents();
```